Is there an equivalent of sqlite3's executemany() in pyside6?
I am trying to read a csv into an sqlite database with Qt SQL (pyside6) but the method I have tried is far too slow.
The sqlite3 module in python has an executemany() function which can insert ~1 million rows very quickly. Using a list as a replacement for csv data:
import sqlite3

# Connect to database
con = sqlite3.connect('./db0.db')
cur = con.cursor()

# Create table
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE foo (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                col1 TEXT(30),
                col2 TEXT(30))''')

# Insert data
data = list(("foo", "bar") for i in range(0, 1000000))
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)", data)

# Close connection
con.commit()
con.close()

In pyside6, the execBatch() method (doc) seems to do something similar but is extremely slow, ~1+ hr (I didn't wait for it to finish). QVariants are mentioned in the documentation but have since been removed. Am I missing something or is there a better method of inserting larger amounts of data?
from PySide6.QtSql import (
    QSqlDatabase,
    QSqlQuery
)

# Connect to database
con = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
con.setDatabaseName('./db0.db')
con.open()

# Create table
query = QSqlQuery()
query.exec('''CREATE TABLE bar (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                col1 TEXT(30),
                col2 TEXT(30)
            )''')

# Insert data
c1 = list("foo" for i in range(0, 100000))
c2 = list("bar" for i in range(0, 100000))

query.prepare("INSERT INTO bar (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)")
query.addBindValue(c1)
query.addBindValue(c2)
query.execBatch()

# Close connection
query.finish()
con.close()

I would prefer to use QT's SQL support over the sqlite3 module for model views.

Have you tried executing the batch within a transaction?

@PeterWolf thanks for the suggestion. Adding con.transaction() before the query and con.commit() afterwards, as described here, has improved performance from an hour to several minutes. It is still not as performant as executemany(), which takes a second or so.

@user15260458 I've never bothered using execBatch, because the performance of calling exec in a loop is perfectly acceptable when used with transactions. For me, running your script with query.prepare("INSERT INTO bar (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)"); for a, b in zip(c1, c2): query.bindValue(0, a); query.bindValue(1, b); query.exec() completes the million inserts in just a few seconds.

@user15260458 After looking at the source code, it seems execBatch just calls exec in a loop as well. I suppose the performance difference comes down to the overhead of marshalling those big Python lists to C++ types.

As suggested in the comments, performance can be improved by starting a transaction, then using a loop and the exec() method, as opposed to execBatch(). The insertion finished in a couple of seconds on my machine.
con.transaction()

query = QSqlQuery()
query.prepare("INSERT INTO bar (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)")

# Insert data
c1 = list("foo" for i in range(0, 1000000))
c2 = list("bar" for i in range(0, 1000000))

query.prepare("INSERT INTO bar (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)")
for a, b in zip(c1, c2):
    query.bindValue(0, a)
    query.bindValue(1, b)
    query.exec()

con.commit()

